# InvokeHelper() throws Access is denied exception

Tags: c++, .net, windows, com, dcom

Community, I have quite interesting and in the same time heavy problem. 
I have VB .NET application + Service + C++ application. C++ application generates some data and makes callbacks using InvokeHelper() method:

```
InvokeHelper(0x60030000, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_EMPTY, NULL, parms,
     eventType, eventValue);
```

The first parameter is the dispid of method which should be called. Strange approach, but this is not my code and I can not change this way.

In service I have method marked by dispid attribute to get this callback from C++ application.

```
<DispId(&H60030000)>
Public Sub ServerEvent(ByVal vEventType As Integer, ByVal vEventValue As Object)
    RaiseEvent ControlPanelStateChange(vEventType, vEventValue)
End Sub
```

This code works correctly if I logged on as admin. But if windows user has not administrator permissions, right after calling InvokeHelper() method the next exception occurs:

> First-chance exception at 0x75B7C42D (KernelBase.dll) in application.exe: 0x80070005: Access is denied

Do you have any ideas? I have played with DCOM permissions, but result is the same.

Any help would be fantastic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of the problem is:

DCOMCNFG, right click on the My Computer and select properties -> COM Securities tab -> Access Permissions -> click Edit Defaults and add Network Service to it and give it Allow local access permission. Do the same for < Machine_name >\Users.

Then -> Launch and Activation Permissions, click Edit Defaults and add Network Service to it and give it Local launch and Local Activation permission. Do the same for < Machine_name >\Users.